# How to get a canvas to constantly redraw itself?

Tags: html, canvas, paint, invalidation

I have a canvas in HTML5 and am making a networked painting application. However, when other clients receive the drawing code, it is not drawn on to the canvas until they mouse over it.

Is there any way to fix it? I'd like the drawing to appear and update to other clients without them having to have their mouse cursor over the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas

```
<html>


<head>
  <script type="application/javascript">
var drawHandle;
function draw() {
  return drawHandle = setTimeout(function(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  ctx.fillStyle = "red";

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(30, 30);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 150);
  // was: ctx.quadraticCurveTo(60, 70, 70, 150); which is wrong.
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(60, 70, 60, 70, 70, 150); // <- this is right formula for the image on the right ->
  ctx.lineTo(30, 30);
  ctx.fill();
}
}, 1000);//Where 1000 is the timeout in milliseconds
   </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="draw()">
   <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```